# Backup procedure using Datapump API

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Hi I try to create Oracle procedure which take backup from user schema (POSData) and place it in directory called "Backups", POSData grant read, write on directory "Backups" using this code from system user.

```
DECLARE
h2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    h2 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT', 'SCHEMA');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2,'POSData.dmp','Backups');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h2,'SCHEMA_EXP','IN (''POSData'')');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h2);
    dbms_datapump.detach(h2);
END;
```

but I always get this error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
h2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
h2 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT', 'SCHEMA');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2,'POSData.dmp','Backups');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h2,'SCHEMA_EXP','IN (''POSData'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h2);
dbms_datapump.detach(h2);
END;
Error report -
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3507
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3756
ORA-06512: at line 5
39001. 00000 - "invalid argument value"
*Cause: The user specified API parameters were of the wrong type or
value range. Subsequent messages supplied by
DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS will further describe the error.
*Action: Correct the bad argument and retry the API.
```

help please?

Comment: Does schema name in uppercase, here: `DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h2,'SCHEMA_EXP','IN (''POSDATA'')');` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem.

Comment: I note that the problem in "DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2,'POSData.dmp','Backups');" line but I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem and here the code

```
                   DECLARE
                         h1 number;
                       errorvarchar varchar2(100):= 'ERROR';
                       tryGetStatus number := 0;
                   begin
                       h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => 'EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_2344', version => 'COMPATIBLE');
                       tryGetStatus := 1;
                       dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle => h1, degree => 1);
                       dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'EXPDAT.LOG', directory => 'BACKUPS', filetype => 3);
                       dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 0);
                       dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'SCHEMA_EXPR', value => 'IN(''POSDATA'')');
                       dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'POSData.DMP', directory => 'BACKUPS', filesize => '100M',  filetype => 1, reusefile => 1);
                       dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1);
                       dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC');
                       dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'ESTIMATE', value => 'BLOCKS');
                       dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0);
                       dbms_datapump.detach(handle => h1);
                       errorvarchar := 'NO_ERROR';
                   EXCEPTION
                       WHEN OTHERS THEN
                       BEGIN
                           IF ((errorvarchar = 'ERROR')AND(tryGetStatus=1)) THEN
                               DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(h1);
                           END IF;
                       EXCEPTION
                       WHEN OTHERS THEN
                           NULL;
                       END;
                       RAISE;
                   END;
```

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_DATAPUMP has some really good error messages, but you have to dig in to get them. In the example below, I added a nested procedure output_expdp_error to dump the detailed message. You should of course modify this to do appropriate logging for your environment:

```
 DECLARE
     h1            NUMBER;
     l_filename    VARCHAR2( 100 ) := 'deleteme.dmp';
     l_directory   VARCHAR2( 100 ) := 'CIFS_DIR';

     PROCEDURE output_expdpd_error( p_handle IN NUMBER ) AS
         -- *******************************************************************
         --  Output EXPDP Error
         --  Purpose:
         --    Send detailed EXPDP error to DBMS_OUTPUT
         --  Modified:
         --    2020.03.02 - BFL Created
         --  Notes:
         --    Borrowed from: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-5AAC848B-5A2B-4FD1-97ED-D3A048263118.htm#SUTIL977
         -- *******************************************************************

         l_status              ku$_status;                                           --ku$_jobstatus;
         l_logentry            ku$_logentry;
         l_job_state           VARCHAR2( 30 );
         l_ind                 NUMBER;
         l_pos                 NUMBER;
         l_length              NUMBER;
         l_linesize   CONSTANT NUMBER := 1000;
         l_message             VARCHAR2( 1000 );
     BEGIN
         -- Original had "if sqlcode = dbms_datapump.success_with_info_num" but this
         -- hides some errors. Just always process the handle.
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Data Pump job started with info available:' );
         DBMS_DATAPUMP.get_status( p_handle
                                 , DBMS_DATAPUMP.ku$_status_job_error
                                 , 0
                                 , l_job_state
                                 , l_status );

         IF (BITAND( l_status.mask, DBMS_DATAPUMP.ku$_status_job_error ) != 0)
         THEN
             l_logentry   := l_status.error;

             IF l_logentry IS NOT NULL
             THEN
                 l_ind   := l_logentry.FIRST;

                 WHILE l_ind IS NOT NULL
                 LOOP
                     l_pos      := 1;
                     l_length   := LENGTH( l_logentry( l_ind ).logtext );
                     l_length   := CASE WHEN l_linesize < l_length THEN l_linesize ELSE l_length END;

                     WHILE l_length > 0
                     LOOP
                         l_message   :=
                             SUBSTR( l_logentry( l_ind ).logtext
                                   , l_pos
                                   , l_length );
                         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( l_message );
                         l_pos      := l_pos + l_linesize;
                         l_length   := LENGTH( l_logentry( l_ind ).logtext ) + 1 - l_pos;
                     END LOOP;

                     l_ind      := l_logentry.NEXT( l_ind );
                 END LOOP;
             END IF;
         END IF;
     END;
 BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'open' );
     h1   := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open( 'EXPORT', 'SCHEMA' );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'add_file' );
     DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file( handle      => h1
                           , filename    => l_filename
                           , directory   => l_directory
                           , filetype    => DBMS_DATAPUMP.ku$_file_type_dump_file
                           , reusefile   => 1 );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'hr filter' );
     DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter( h1
                                  , 'SCHEMA_EXPR'
                                  , 'IN (''BOGUS'')' );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'BOGUS filter' );
     DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter( h1
                                  , 'SCHEMA_EXPR'
                                  , 'IN (''BOGUS'')' );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'start_job' );
     DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job( h1 );
     DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach( h1 );
 EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
         DECLARE
             l_message   VARCHAR2( 1000 );
         BEGIN
             output_expdpd_error( p_handle => h1 );
             DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach( h1 );
             l_message   :=
                 SUBSTR(
                        SQLERRM
                     || UTL_TCP.crlf
                     || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace
                     || UTL_TCP.crlf
                     || UTL_TCP.crlf
                   , 1
                   , 1000 );
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( l_message );
             raise_application_error( -20000, l_message );
         END;
 END;
```

When I ran this with the non-existent schema, I got the wonderfully specific error message:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression IN ('BOGUS') does not correspond to any schemas.
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3507
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4825
ORA-06512: at line 76
```